# Allow user to customize page sections

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

Is it possible to allow a user to customize sections of our website to match their look and feel? For example, to modify logos and CSS, possibly pointing back to their site for the actual content. Ideally I would also like a third-party (ASP.NET) tool to manage this, rather than coding a hack myself.

Edited: I want a solution where a customer can just use a menu to modify the attributes they want, so that there is no need for me to interact with the customer at all.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a CMS (Content Management System), there are lots out there. Just find one that suits you.

I hear [Sitefinity](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitefinity.com%2F&rct=j&q=sitefinity&ei=QWjxTNTRL8H48Aa1r8S1DA&usg=AFQjCNEXrLvFR6YN0Xt94Q035soJ5LQvdQ&sig2=VNYDLhMET7pvOwspVb1NZQ&cad=rja) is good.

Comment: Looks interesting, but a bit of overkill for my project. Ideally I want something that is focussed solely on allowing the basics to be modified, but without all the additional features that SF offers...

Comment: well there are other options out there, I'd suggest you look into them.

Comment: ... and the other options ;-)?

Comment: Google for `CMS`? You just want everything handed to you.

Comment: @customPages: Other developers use this forum to ask for or give advice. People are not necessarily here to GIVE you the answers. Besides there may be a wide range of answers (as in this case) and it is therefore up to you, as the developer, to decide which one is best. It may be worth deploying one and asking several of the actual end users to try it out. If they don't like it then try another. To be honest I would personally just code it myself - but this approach depends on how much time you have to complete this project.